# Script A launches script B, and then script C when B closes

Tags: python, arduino

I would like to write a script (A) that automatically launches another script (B). Then, when B is closed, script C is launched.

I have played around with subprocess, but I couldn't get the hang of it. It just opened the file, it didn't run it.

I tried creating a function in script C that launches B's UI, which you can then close to reveal C's UI.
That one worked when testing on my windows machine, but did not work when running on the Raspberry Pi it is intended for. The issue was "focus" didn't go to the user input box on the second UI.

(details: I work in medical simulation, and this project is for a simulated ultrasound machine. I have an RFID reader running off an arduino board connected to the computer by USB. The arduino sends the ID number as key strokes. The python scripts then displays an image associated with that ID number. In a simulation, a physician may perform an ultrasound, perform interventions on the patient, and then repeat the ultrasound to see the result of that intervention. I want to be able to display pre and post intervention images. The RFID tags are stuck under our mannequin's skin)

---

I tried the suggestion below:

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.call(['python.exe', "C:\\Users\\SimLab\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py"])
sp.call(['python.exe', "C:\\Users\\SimLab\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\TEMPLATE_POST_INTERVENTION.py"])
```

It launches the second script, and closing it does not reveal the first one.
It looks like the first one starts but gets killed by the second right away.

Actually, that is only true when trying things on a windows computer.
When I tried running this on RPi I get a different set of error messages.
At first, it was permission errors. So I changed permission settings on the file and folder where the python scripts are saved.
Now I am getting the following error message:

> b''
> b'
> /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: import: not found\n
> /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: 2: /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: import: not found\n
> from: can't read /var/mail/PyQt5\n
> from: can't read /var/mail/PyQt5.QtCore\n
> from: can't read /var/mail/PyQt5.QtGui\n
> from: can't read /var/mail/PyQt5.QtWidgets\n
> /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: 10: /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: WINDOW_STYLE: not found\n
> /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: 15: /home/pi/Desktop/code/TEMPLATE_PRE_INTERVENTION.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected\n'

So I am working on that now.

And this is the first python file I am trying to load. The second is very similar, just with a different dictionary set.

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


WINDOW_STYLE = '''
background-color:black; 
color:white;
'''

class Ui_Widget(QWidget):
    
    # You need to change this
    CARD_DICT = {
        # PIN:  IMAGE_PATH
        '13603461233126': 'images/1.png',    # Right lung
        '1360743335192': 'images/2.png',    # Left lung apex
        '1360341692930': 'images/3.png',    # Left heart
        '136073147157207': 'images/4.png',  # Spleen
        '136075353245': 'images/5.png',     # Subxiphoid cardiac
        # '136072179130241': 'images/6.png',  # Diaphragm?
        # '136073133188248': 'images/7.png',  # Supra umbilicus
        # '136035223197177': 'images/8.png',  # right lateral
        # '1360341562547': 'images/9.png',    # left lateral
        # '13607311245156': 'images/10.png',   # Sub umbilicus
        # the following are for testing purposes only
        '60013620412116': 'images/6.png',  # Diaphragm?
        '13603447120253': 'images/7.png',  # Supra umbilicus
        '1360341002204': 'images/8.png',  # right lateral
        '13607217912415': 'images/9.png',    # left lateral
        '136073209222206': 'images/10.png',   # Sub umbilicus
    }

        
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Widget, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Simulated Ultrasound')
        # Full screen
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        # No close, minimize and miximaze window button
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet(WINDOW_STYLE)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Widget):
        Widget.setObjectName("Widget")
        Widget.resize(800, 600)

        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Widget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(50)
        
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(780, 0))
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMinimumSize)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum
        )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 10))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(
            40, 10, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum
        )
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Widget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 26))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Widget)
        # I think this is the line to change to make it launch another script
        self.pushButton.pressed.connect(Widget.close) # type: ignore
        # self.pushButton.pressed.connect(Widget.post_intervention) # type: ignore
        # Check every time the text line input changed
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.submit_pass) # type: ignore

    def retranslateUi(self, Widget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate

        Widget.setWindowTitle(_translate("Widget", "Widget"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Widget", "Scan patient to begin"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Widget", "PIN Phrase"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Widget", "Template: PRE-intervention"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Widget", "Click here after performing interventions"))

    def submit_pass_str(self, input_str):
        """here the application accept user input"""
        if input_str in self.CARD_DICT:
            self.display_image(self.CARD_DICT[input_str])
            self.label_2.setText('')
        else:
            self.label_2.setText(f'Invalid: {input_str}')

    def display_image(self, path):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
        if ext and ext.lower() == '.gif':
            movie = QMovie(path)
            self.label.setMovie(movie)
            movie.start()
        else:
            image = QPixmap(path)
            self.label.setPixmap(image)
        self.label.setMinimumSize(1, 1)

    def submit_pass(self):
        """Usage example using PIN Phrase input form"""
        self.submit_pass_str(self.lineEdit.text())




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui_Widget()
window.show()
# sys.exit(post_intervention())
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This isn't an Arduino question

Answer (score 0):

Without proper details, examples, error messages and so on from you, the following should do as you ask.

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.run("scriptB")
sp.run("scriptC")
```

If that doesn't work, please click the `edit` button under your original question and add details of what happens and why/how it doesn't work.

Comment: I knew I should have included code, but honestly it was all just slight tweaks of different examples I found online. 
Your suggestion worked... kinda. It just doesn't seem to wait for the first one to end before starting the second.